# how to display database with javascript in the form of a table?

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite

I have problems with my application that is when it will display the data from the database in the form of a data table that happen to two sideways instead of down 
[image]

main.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var sql = ign.sql();
var driver = sql.driver("sqlite","peserta.sqlite");
var qry = sql.query("select * from data");

if(driver){
    //$(".json").html(JSON.stringify(qry));
    var query = qry;
    var html = "";

    $("p").html("Status Database Connection : "+query.status);
    if(query.status){

         $.each(query.content,function(data){
            html += "<td>"+this.no+"</td>";
            html += "<td>"+this.nama+"</td>";
            html += "<td>"+this.alamat+"</td>";
        });
    }

    $(".data").html(html);
}
```

});

this HTML

```
<!doctype html>
```

```
<p></p>
<!--
<h2>JSON Data</h2>
<div class="json"></div><hr> -->
<table>
<tr>
<td>No</td>
<td>Nama</td>
<td>Alamat</td>
</tr>
<tr class="data">
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: wait this has nothing to do with your question but what linux distro is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the  tags (table row) around your rows. Something like this should work:

```
$.each(query.content,function(data){
        html += "<tr>";
        html += "<td>"+this.no+"</td>";
        html += "<td>"+this.nama+"</td>";
        html += "<td>"+this.alamat+"</td>";
        html += "</tr>";
    });
```

Comment: thanks for the answer , but that's not what I mean , should the name of the column underneath the line no , row underneath the name of the column nama and so on .

Comment: @HaviedzMiftah, ah ok, I understand. That's a bit more complicated, since html doesn't directly allow for "horizontal tables". But you could do it by using [this structure](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_header), though then you have to use several loops, one for numbers, one for name and one for alamat to generate each row.

Comment: but I do not understand the existing code between the script tags

Answer (score 0):

In your html, replace

```
<tr class="data">
```

with

```
<tbody class="data">
```

and in your jQuery, do what @thorsten has suggested.

Also, you might have to replace the `<td>` tags in your static html to `<th>`, to make them headings and force browsers to render it as .